# How to disable link deletion in UML state diagram in Jointjs?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, jointjs

I have UML state diagram drawn using jointjs and the various states are connected through links. On hovering over the links, a cross symbol appears upon clicking which the link gets removed. I want to disable the cross symbol over the link.

Comment: Please elaborate and share your code

Comment: @samar i cannot share the code...but you can see the sample code from http://resources.jointjs.com/demos/umlsc

Comment: @AnupamSingh this doesn't seem to be a programming issue and is therefore off-topic here. If you want to know how to use some piece of software you'll need to seek help elsewhere I'm afraid.

Comment: @Robert Longson All I'm asking that is there any API in jointjs which I can use to disable deleting the links in the UML state diagram

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a custom link extending from joint.dia.link and use that link for your charts. Look into joint.core.js for more details and joint.shapes.uml.js

Step1. Create your custom uml link either by extending directly from joint.dia.link or by extending from the below

- joint.shapes.uml.Generalization
- joint.shapes.uml.Implementation
- joint.shapes.uml.Aggregation
- joint.shapes.uml.Composition
- joint.shapes.uml.Association

  joint.shapes.yourLink = joint.dia.Link.extend({

//to remove the cross that removes the link modify the toolMarkUp to not show anything as below and use your new link

```
toolMarkup: [
].join(''),
```

add the remaining attributes that you currently have for the link like source, target etc

})

sample code from my project

```
  joint.shapes.deviceLink = joint.dia.Link.extend({

 // i modified the vertexMarkup to not create vertexes.
    vertexMarkup: [
        '<g class="marker-vertex-group" transform="translate(<%= x %>, <%= y %>)">',
        '<circle class="marker-vertex" idx="<%= idx %>" r="1" />',
        '</g>'
    ].join(''),


    defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
      type: 'deviceLink',
        connection: { name: 'orthogonal' },
        attrs: {
           '.connection': { stroke: '#fe854f', 'stroke-width': 3 },
            sourcePort:{text:''},
            targetPort:{text:''},
            '.link-tools .tool-remove circle': { r: 8, fill:'#fff',position: 0.5 },
        },
        labels: [ { position: 0.5, attrs: { text: { text: '' } } }  ]

    }, joint.dia.Link.prototype.defaults),
  });

  joint.shapes.deviceLinkView = joint.dia.LinkView.extend({
    mouseover: function (evt, x, y) {
   //my custom mouseover function
    },
    mouseout: function (evt, x, y) {
  // my custom mouseout function
  });
```